# RewriteEngine. Подмена запроса

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

Привет!

Хочу замаскировать запрос такого вида:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?group=fruits&subgroup=apples
```

на такой:

```
http://domain.com/food/fruits/apples/
```

Нужно чтобы можно было перейти и просто по адресу "/fruits/" и по "/fruits/apples/".

И делаю я это так. Создаю файл .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^food/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^food/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?group=$1&subgroup=$2 [L]
```

Работает.

Но если в запросе убрать последний слеш, то в строке в браузере после перехода появится такое чудо:

```
http://domain.com/food/sweets/candies/?group=sweets&subgroup=candies
```

Что я делаю не так?
Как сделать чтобы можно было переходить и со слешем в конце, и без?

Comment: ротер в самом index.php напишите, не мучайте апач.

Comment: а если не хочется, то через RewriteCond просто запретите  эти условия выполнять, если есть файл

    RewriteCond !-f

кажется так.

Comment: на сколько мне помнится то перед последним слешем в условии ставится символ "|" чтобы работало со слешем и без